# Is Caching enable by default in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, browser, browser-cache

I am new in angularjs and according to this [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for using cache in $http service we most add this option to configuration:

```
$http({
    method : "GET",
    url : "somehost/somepath",
    cache : true
}) ;
```

witch means caching is disabled by default, but in real world when i use this configuration :

```
  $http({
    method : "GET",
    url : "somehost/somepath"
}) ;
```

I see this result:
[image]

How can i turn off this caching system?

Comment: Do you have `dev tools` setup to not cache?  You need to make sure that is toggled correctly or it will never cache with `dev tools` open

Comment: this means when i 'use dev' tools this enable my caching? and if i access to my site with out 'dev tools' it  work normally ?

Comment: an alternative solution would be simply adding a dummy random parameter at the end of your url and make yourself free of annoying browser configurations and different levels of caching! ( e.g. `url : "somehost/somepath?"+Math.random()` )

Comment: thank you for your helpful suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *browser caching*, the browser cached the result not AngularJS, this is allowed per the [HTTP protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html). You can control what and how much is being cached in the backend of your application.

A typical way to deal with caching of files is versioning (or "revving" them), if the file has a different URL the browser will not load it from its cache.